# approximate all intersections between lines segments

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

Is there a way to approximate all the intersections between a set of line segments?

I don't want to calculate all `O(N^2)` intersections, it will take to long time.

**Edit:** I would like an algorithm that somehow calculates the average intersection point of the lines. The thing is that I have an unknown amount of outlier lines (bad lines) and noise.
So no two lines will intersect exactly. Some **L1** or **L2** minimization will be hard also since we have outliers. Any nice sampling algorithm?
I guess I could sample two lines, calculate their intersection and then see how many lines passes through a epsilon circle around that intersection point. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of output you would expect?

Comment: You could take a random sample of your segments, and compute their intersections.

Comment: How many segments are there?

Comment: If the segments aren't all packed densely together, it might be useful to use a [spatial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index#Spatial_index) like a quadtree. Then you only have to compare line segments that are close to one another.

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting all these intersections to be concentrated in a small number of regions.  Is that correct?  Otherwise I don't see how you could get a meaningful approximation.

Comment: Sounds a little like a Hough transform which solves the problem by drawing each line and counting the bucket with the most hits

Comment: You can use the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm to improve upon the performance of computing all of the intersections.  It offers O(N^2/log N) time complexity rather than the O(N^2) of the naive approach.

Comment: "So no two lines will intersect exactly" ?? i think you need to draw a picture because your question really doesnt make any sense.